# How to find directory of copied files from library in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to bundle a series of files from an imported library onto the simulator/iphone in Xcode 6.0, but I'm not quite sure how to find the directory these files are located in.

I still don't have enough reputation to post photos, but you can see how I'm attempting to copy the files over here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgFhH.png

Ideally, I'm looking for function, in swift, that would return a string containing the directory path for these files. I'm still new to programming in iOS so forgive me if I'm doing something incorrect or my terminology is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSBundle to get the path for a resource:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Name", ofType: "extension")
```

Comment: Well this give the full path to the file or just the path of the directory? I can always work with the full path but it would be nice just to get the directory.

Comment: This returns the full path. I think you can use the `resourcePath` property of NSBundle for the path of the directory. However, `pathForResource` contains extra logic to work with localized resources. I recommend to use that since it abstracts the actual file structure of the bundle.

Comment: Okay, so I tried using that example and it returns nil. I've used that exact function before, but it was to get files that were bundled directly within the project directory. In this instance the files are bundled in a project/framework that has been added to my project.

Comment: Try changing the destination to "Resources". If that doesn't work, remove the copy phase and drag the resources from the sidebar into the "Copy bundle resources" phase. You can uncheck 'copy files' so you don't end up with two copies, but this depends on your file structure.

Comment: thanks I read further into the documentation and it turns out you have to copy the library resources directly into the project directory. Using your function I'm now able to find the path to the file.